# Send php variable to two pages

Tags: php, forms

I have a `form.html`. When user submit the form the variable will be send to `page1.php`. This `page1.php` will store nameserver input to database, make dig query, store the dig output to database and after that user will be redirected to `form.html`.

The trouble is with the dig query. It can sometimes take 3-5 seconds before dig get any reply and user will be redirected to `form.html`. Thats mean the user had to wait with no response at `form.html` for 3-5 seconds before redirect to `form.html` again.

I was thinking this solution. `form.html` redirect to `page1.php`. `page1.php` will only store user input to database after that redirect user to `form.html`. At the same time `page1.php` will send user input to `page2.php` and make dig query. So that was the question actually. How do I send data to `page1.php` and redirect user to `form.html` at the same time send data to `page2.php` to make background dig query and store the dig output to database. I don't know how to do that.

Since I don't need instantaneous result I don't think I need AJAX or jquery to make dig query. User will just see output taken from database anyway.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want them to have to wait on the form submission? Most of the web is used to forms taking a few seconds to do their thing.

Comment: You could use sessions then use the data you need on any page...

Comment: I'm saving user nameserver. Sometimes dig gave error output after a long time. I need to stored this nameserver to database and make query for later time. Maybe I'm not answering your question but I prefer to redirect user quickly.

Comment: I'd suggest a flush() approach, but as soon as the user closes the page, execution will halt.

Comment: The problem has been solved but by using AJAX. Thanks to DaveE for his suggestion. I appreciate everyone one input. Here is the solution >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247252/jquery-redirect-after-submit-to-1-page Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to use Ajax, how about passing the information via a hidden iframe to make the dig query on the first page that you process the submit information?

Comment: Are you saying on `page1.php` I will pass the variable via hidden iframe?

Comment: Yes, put an `iframe` on `page1.php` and hide it with `style="display:none"`.  Put the `src` of the `iframe` to the URL that you want to load in the background.  Pass the variables that you need to via querystring.

Comment: How do I execute the iframe? Is this the correct way to do it on `page1.php`: `echo "<iframe style=\"display:none\" src=\"http://myweb.com/page2.php?ns1=ns01.000webhost.com.&ns2=ns01.000webhost.com.&id=70&zone=272\"></iframe>";` I test but the data is not being send to the page2.php page? Thank you.

Comment: Yes that looks right.  The data would definitely be getting sent to the page2.php page.  Make sure you are using `$_GET` to receive it.

Comment: The problem has been solved but I end up using AJAX instead. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Ajax is the way to go for sure

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you don't think you need ajax, but, I think it's your best and easiest bet. Have a look at the [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). It's incredibly easy to implement and you can easily use one of its callback methods to make your second form submission.

Comment: I already take a look. I found that many example only show submit data to current page with no page refresh. Perhaps you could point me to `use one of its callback methods to make your second form submission.` like you said? Maybe I'm looking at different thing, I don't know. Anyway I appreciate your help.

Comment: I end up using  AJAX. Thanks for your advice.