# Jquery redirect after submit to 1 page

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form. This form will submit data to 2 different pages. After submit data to `hidd.php` I will redirect user to `index.php`. At the same time after submit data to `hidd.php`, data will be submitted to `ns.php`. I don't want to wait for output from both page just quickly redirect user after submit data to `hidd.php`. So that was the question, how to redirect user without waiting for output after submit. Why I want to do this? It's a long story, I even thought about using curl >> [Send php variable to two pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242266/send-php-variable-to-two-pages)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST', 
        url: 'hidd.php', 
        data:$('#ContactForm').serialize(), 
});

        $.ajax({
        type:'POST', 
        url: 'ns.php',
        data:$('#ContactForm').serialize(), 
});


    return false;
}
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="ContactForm" onsubmit="return submitForm();">
    Your subdomain: <input type="text" name="subdomain" value="" /><br /> 
    Your ns1: <input type="text" name="ns1" value="" /><br /> 
    Your ns2:<br /> <input type="text" name="ns2" value="" />
    <br /><br /> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /><br />
    <div class="form_result"> </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should serialize #ContactForm in single variable and then add it to data of both posts.

Comment: But I guess if you do that your other request won't run. You can do it on `success` on your second submission, and that'll be as soon as possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the $.post method. I'm not sure the structure of your php files but you can handle the posted data however you like.

html change from:

```
  <form id="ContactForm" onsubmit="return submitForm();">
        Your subdomain: <input type="text" name="subdomain" value="" /><br /> 
        Your ns1: <input type="text" name="ns1" value="" /><br /> 
        Your ns2:<br /> <input type="text" name="ns2" value="" />
        <br /><br /> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /><br />
        <div class="form_result"> </div>
    </form>
```

to:

```
<form id="ContactForm">
    Your subdomain: <input type="text" name="subdomain" value="" id="subDomain" /><br /> 
    Your ns1: <input type="text" name="ns1" value="" id="ns1" /><br /> 
    Your ns2:<br /> <input type="text" name="ns2" value="" id="ns2" />
    <br /><br /> 
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton" /><br />
    <div class="form_result"> </div>
</form>
```

the javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submitButton').click(function(){
        var subDomain = $('#subDomain').val();
        var ns1 = $('#ns1').val();
        var ns2 = $('#ns2').val();
            $.post('hidd.php', {
                subDomain : subDomain,
                ns1 : ns1,
                ns2 : ns2
            });
            $.post('ns.php', {
                subDomain : subDomain,
                ns1 : ns1,
                ns2 : ns2
            }, function(){
               location.href="index.php";
            });

        });
    });
```

changing the button from a submit to a button will stop the automatic redirect so you don't have to return false. Then you are free to redirect when you want.

Comment: You got error with this `subDomain : subDomain,`. What is the difference if the `function(){
               location.href="index.php";
            }` is after `ns.php` function instead of `hidd.php` function. I put it after `hidd.php` function and it still redirect but I'm not sure whether the redirect actually happen after the `hidd.php` or putting it anywhere make no different at all. I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: im not sure why there is an error with the subDomain part. It should work as written. As for where you put the redirect, I put it after ns.php just because i wanted to have it run after both scripts were posted to. I wouldn't put it before you post to the second script as it may not have the post fire with the data in it. but you also don't necessarily have to put it in the callback function of the second post. You can put it after both posts and it should still work just fine.

Comment: My mistake. I change `id=subDomain` to `id=subdomain` and claim it was an error. It was an error on my part.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$.ajax({ /** params **/ });
$.ajax({ /** params **/ });
location.href='index.php';
```

Comment: I try that and my second ajax function won't run.